# Fetch information from internet to display in app

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have an idea for an app that would require fetching scheduling information from a website, in particular a local transit company. I have not done any work in WP applications that involves drawing information from the internet, and I have no idea where to start with that.

What is the best way to learn how to achieve this within Windows Phone? Any namedropping of things to look up or places to start would be appreciated.

Comment: Asking for external resources is unfortunately considered as Off topic!

Comment: Then anything to put me in the right direction would be appreciated. Doesn't have to be external resources.

Comment: You may need to invest time here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402529%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: I have written apps before. I'm not sure you understand my question. I'm looking for information on fetching from the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is EXTREMELY vague, which is notoriously a no no on S.O. so here is a vague answer in return.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

wc.DownloadStringAsyncCompleted += (s,a) => 
{
  var results = a.Result; // Your web result 

};

wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(@"http://www.Google.com",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

If you are interested in a real explanation hit me up on twitter or at amr@AnthonyRussell.info I will try and get you up to speed. StackOverflow is not a place for questions like this.